# Using JavaScript to perform a GET request without AJAX

Tags: javascript

Out of curiosity, I'm wondering about the best (easiest, fastest, shortest, etc; make your pick) way to perform a GET request in JavaScript without using AJAX or any external libraries.

It must work cross-browser and it's not allowed to distort the hosting web page visually or affect it's functionality in any way.

I don't care about headers in the request, just the url-part. I also don't care about the result of the request. I just want the server to do something as a side effect when it receives this request, so firing it is all that matters. If your solution requires the servers to return something in particular, that's ok as well.

I'll post my own suggestion as a possible answer, but I would love it if someone could find a better way!

Comment: Do you need to work with the return value, or is making the request enough?

Comment: This is a really wierd thing to do. Why wouldn't you just make a request via AJAX?

Comment: One could create an iframe dynamically, and load the resource in there. If it's on the same domain, you can even access the return data

Comment: @annakata: this piece of code is required in an environment where I can't use external libraries and cross-browser AJAX in that case is a little messy. An easier solution should be possible (especially since I don't need something returned from the request)

Comment: @Jakob - Messier than a clunky create/remove script element which achieves what you want almost as a side effect? A fire-and-forget AJAX GET is the correct solution because it does exactly what you want and no more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Have you tried using an Image object? Something like:

```
var req = new Image();
req.onload = function() {
    // Probably not required if you're only interested in
    // making the request and don't need a callback function
}
req.src = 'http://example.com/foo/bar';
```

Comment: Ah, I don't have to actually include the image on the page? Clever.

Comment: unless the response is valid image, I don't think onload will be executed, just `onerror`. :)

Comment: Image could always be a transparent px or hidden or positioned -1000px offscreen...

Comment: I've done something similar before and did what @annakata suggests and just returned a 1px x 1px transparent image after the server had finished processing the request.

Answer (score 1):

```
function GET(url) {
  var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
  var n = document.createElement('script');
  n.src = url;
  n.type = 'text/javascript';
  n.onload = function() { // this is not really mandatory, but removes the tag when finished.
    head.removeChild(n);
  };
  head.appendChild(n);
}
```

Comment: You probably want to hit it onerror too. It might not be a script.

Comment: The `n.type = 'text/javascript';` surprisingly so, is unnecessary. The fun part is that the request is optimistically made here `n.src = url;` (yes, the assignment triggers the request) but the result is obviously not available until you add it to the document. FYI the Google Maps JavaScript API loads like this. On a related note, Comet applications can be implemented like this by streaming a continuous javascript for partial evaluation to enable push notifications at very low response times.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with Pekka idea and use hidden iframe, the advantage is that no further parsing will be done: for image, the browser will try to parse the result as image, for dynamically creating `script` tag the browser will try to parse the results as JavaScript code.. iframe is "hit and run", the browser doesn't care what's in there.

Changing your own solution a bit:

```
function GET(url) {
    var oFrame = document.getElementById("MyAjaxFrame");
    if (!oFrame) {
        oFrame = document.createElement("iframe");
        oFrame.style.display = "none";
        oFrame.id = "MyAjaxFrame";
        document.body.appendChild(oFrame);
    }
    oFrame.src = url;
}
```