# How does jQuery (and others) actually do the GET request in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Its a bit unclear how Javascript internally is doing the request. I know its not using the build-in

browser XMLHttpRequest, but how does it do it? Read an article on stackoverflow where they simply create a Javascript

object and set the 
var obj = document.createElement('script');
obj.src = "http://somedomain.com?blabla=yes"

[Using JavaScript to perform a GET request without AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4490143/using-javascript-to-perform-a-get-request-without-ajax)

Here from jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: url,
        async: false,
        jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log("console. hurra");
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    });
```

Do you know how does jQuery internally build up the request in Javascript and submit it?

I tried this locally and it worked like charm in the sense that the the script was inserted correctly in my page.
var CampaignNs = {

```
GET: function(url) {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var n = document.createElement('script');
    n.src = url;
    n.type = 'text/javascript';
    n.onload = function() { // this is not really mandatory, but removes the tag when finished.
        head.removeChild(n);
    };
    head.appendChild(n);
}
```

}

I advance thanks

Good article here:
http://johnnywey.wordpress.com/2012/05/20/jsonp-how-does-it-work/#comment-359

Comment: Have you tried looking at the jQuery source code?

Comment: Search for `ajax:` in [the source code](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js).

Comment: Is the question only *"what's the source code for the ajax function ?"* ? If that's the case, I'll vote to close.

Comment: Are you talking about JSONP specifically?

Comment: "I know its not using the build-in (sic) browser XMLHttpRequest" - well, you'd be wrong.

Comment: "I know its not using the build-inbrowser XMLHttpRequest". ... Search for 'XMLHttpRequest' in the source code.

Comment: Sometimes it uses XMLHttpReqest, sometimes it doesn't. The source code is available if you want the details. The question is too broad at present.

Comment: Just for clarification: yes, I only spoke about JsonP in the original question, which doesn't use XMLHttpRequest, I see now in retrospective that I was unclear on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using XHTTPRequest or inserting  tags are both valid ways to trigger GET requests. XHTTPRequests are cleaner in many ways tough because they don't involve messing around in the DOM.

> Its a bit unclear how Javascript internally is doing the request. I
>   know its not using the build-in
>
> browser XMLHttpRequest, but how does it do it?

This makes no sense. JavaScript (i.e. the JavaScript implementation in your browser) need not rely on XHTTPRequest, it just invokes the browser's HTTP APIs if it needs to do requests. Which it doesn't need to do except through XHTTPRequest :-)

Comment: Thanks! And thanks to the initial comments. I looked through the source code and found it. I understand now that JsonP basically is just like loading any Javascript file. These frameworks only create a script tag, set the script URL attribute and when the script tag is added to the DOM the browser makes the GET request. Then I also finally understood why we with this technique only can perform GET and not PUT, POST and DELETE